# Help required regarding Cypress 4200 coding

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, development, capsense, cortex-m0

I am a newbie when it comes to Cypress chips. I am developing a capsense keypad.

I recently started with CY8kit049. I can code into the chip on board. How can I code other PSOC 4200 chips too using it? The bootloader accepts bootloadable programs directly. But when the chips will be new, they won't have any bootloader loaded in them.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does that device not have JTAG or some other kind of in-circuit programming mechanism?

Comment: Simply use a SWD debugger/flasher. Works for any ARM. Unless you have very specialized requirements, bootloaders are a thing of the previous millennium, before the dawn of JTAG/SWD.

Comment: Here you can find all the information you need https://community.cypress.com/docs/DOC-10852

Comment: Actually bootloaders endure in the era of SWD, both in factory ROM and custom versions.  They serve somewhat different purposes, SWD being used for serious development and debug but bootloaders being useful for in-service updates and lightweight development.  Pretty much any serious vendor of ARM Cortex parts offers documentation on both.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/92635/g36 
Thanks!